# How can I use an existing relationship to create multiple navigational properties based on it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I have two tables, say:

Teacher 1-------* Pupil

I only have one navigational property named 'Pupils'.

Just for this example, what I would like to do is create two navigational properties named 'Boys' and another called 'Girls', which would be based on a bool named 'IsMale'.

I have generated the Entity model from the database, so this is not code-first.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?  Do I need to modify the generated source?  If so, what happens if an update occurs, will I lose the code?

Thanks for your time!

Craig

Here is my solution:

Add a navigational property and, in the properties, select the association between the teacher and pupil.

In the generated code, find the navigational property, 'Boys', add a .where to the end which will select the boys, like:

```
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("SchoolModel", "FK_Pupils_Teacher", "Pupil")]
    public EntityCollection<Pupil> Boys
    {
        get
        {
            return (EntityCollection<PriceKey>)((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<PriceKey>("SchoolModel.FK_Pupils_Teacher", "Pupil").Where(p => p.IsMale == true);
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Pupil>("SchoolModel.FK_Pupils_Teacher", "Pupil", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

That is my solution.  So now I can use the navigational property and will pass back what I would like.

I also like the answer below!  And think that one is a better idea though :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `Teacher.cs` file in the folder your `.EDMX` file is in:

```
partial class Teacher
{
    public IEnumerable<Pupil> Boys
    {
        get { return Pupils.Where(x => x.IsMale); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Pupil> Girls
    {
        get { return Pupils.Where(x => !x.IsMale); }
    }
}
```

By the way, these are not navigate properties. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, except wouldn't that cause a conflict with the existing teacher class?  I have done something that should also work too, I'll add it to the question

Comment: No, it won't. This is partial class feature supported since C# 2.0. The EF Designer generated classes are partial classes.

Comment: Ohhhhh.  Great!  Think I better read on these partial classes! Thanks for the great answer!!!